# Apache server Directiva Location

Tags: apache, apache2

Estoy intentando usar la directiva Location para mostrar la ventana de usuario/contraseña cuando no se cumple dicha directiva.

Cuando el path no es:

- /elastic/bundles/...
- /elastic/ui/...
- /elastic/api/...
- /elastic/plugins/...
- /elastic/app/...

la ventana debe mostrarse.
Mi configuración del Location:

```
<Location ~ "!((/elastic/bundles/)|(/elastic/ui/)|(/elastic/api/)|(/elastic/plugins/)|(/elastic/app/))>
    AuthUserFile /passwordPath
    AuthName "auth_name"
    AuthType Basic
    require valid-user
</Location>
```

Pero cuando accedo a un path que no es ninguno de los descritos arriba no se muestra el prompt. ¿Alguna idea?
Gracias